# Sidekiq job execution context

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I want to perform some tasks in background but with something like "run as". In other words, like a task was launched by the user from the context of his session.

Something like

```
def perform
    env['warden'].set_user(@task_owner_user)
    MyService::current_user_dependent_method
end
```

but I'm not sure it' won't collide with other tasks. I'm not very familiar with Sidekiq.
Can I safely perform separate tasks, each with a different user context, somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your shooting for with the "run as" context, but I've always setup sidekiq jobs that need a unique object by passing the id in the perform. This way the worker always knows which object it is trying to work on. Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
    def perform id
        user = User.find(id)
        user.current_user_dependent_method
    end
```

Then setup a route in a controller for triggering this worker to start, something like:

```
  def custom_route_for_performing_job
    @users= User.where(your_conditions)
    @users.each do |user|
      YourWorker.perform_async user.id
    end
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Starting background job for users_dependent_method"
  end
```

Comment: Your answer led me to the right way. Need more encapsulation in some parts of my code :) Seems it was just a bad design to made services dependent on the usual request flow. Just had not thought earlier I will use background workers.

Answer (score 2):

The proper design is to use a server-side middleware + a thread local variable to set the current user context per job.

```
class MyServerMiddlware
  def call(worker, message, queue)
    Thread.current[:current_user] = message['uid'] if message['uid']
    yield
  ensure
    Thread.current[:current_user] = nil
  end
end
```

You'd create a client-side middleware to capture the current uid and put it in the message.  In this way, the logic is encapsulated distinctly from any one type of Worker.  Read more:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware

Comment: I didn't mentioned that the majority of tasks are executed by system, so there is no 'current user' to capture before an actual task starts. I retrieve one from the database by schedule. There is the rub.